# Error in installing from github the tidyverse/dplyr package on supercomputer

Tags: r, github, installation, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to update my `tidyverse` `dplyr` package to use the function `across` as shown in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615137/cant-find-function-across-in-mutate). However I get the following error. Any help?

```
> devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
Downloading GitHub repo tidyverse/dplyr@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/tidyverse/dplyr/zipball/master
Installing dplyr
'/usr/local/app/conda-R/conda-R-5.1/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ  \
  --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/Rtmp4NOex8/devtools2bf3846ae3693/tidyverse-dplyr-0841f52'  \
  --library='/export/projects/AAA/code/R/pkg_library'  \
  --install-tests 

ERROR: dependencies ‘ellipsis’, ‘generics’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/export/projects/AAA/code/R/pkg_library/dplyr’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

I tried adding the option `dependencies = TRUE`, but I got the same result.

```
> devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)
Downloading GitHub repo tidyverse/dplyr@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/tidyverse/dplyr/zipball/master
Installing dplyr
'/usr/local/app/conda-R/conda-R-5.1/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ  \
  --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/Rtmp4NOex8/devtools2bf38103e4ad6/tidyverse-dplyr-0841f52'  \
  --library='/export/projects/AAA/code/R/pkg_library'  \
  --install-tests 

ERROR: dependencies ‘ellipsis’, ‘generics’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/export/projects/jtamayo_Energy_Col_project/code/R/pkg_library/dplyr’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

------- UPDATE

Given the comment below, I reinstalled `dplyr`, but the latest version I get is `0.7.6`, not `1.1`. How to get the latest version? I tried `install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE, version ="1.1")`

```
                Information on package ‘dplyr’

Description:

Type:               Package
Package:            dplyr
Title:              A Grammar of Data Manipulation
Version:            0.7.6
Authors@R:          c( person("Hadley", "Wickham", ,
                    "hadley@rstudio.com", c("aut", "cre"), comment =
                    c(ORCID = "0000-0003-4757-117X")), person("Romain",
                    "Fran\u00e7ois", role = "aut", comment = c(ORCID =
                    "0000-0002-2444-4226")), person("Lionel", "Henry",
                    role = "aut"), person("Kirill", "M\u00fcller", role
                    = "aut", comment = c(ORCID =
                    "0000-0002-1416-3412")), person("RStudio", role =
                    c("cph", "fnd")) )
Description:        A fast, consistent tool for working with data frame
                    like objects, both in memory and out of memory.
License:            MIT + file LICENSE
URL:                http://dplyr.tidyverse.org,
                    https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr
BugReports:         https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues
Depends:            R (>= 3.1.2)
Imports:            assertthat (>= 0.2.0), bindrcpp (>= 0.2.0.9000),
                    glue (>= 1.1.1), magrittr (>= 1.5), methods,
                    pkgconfig (>= 2.0.1), R6 (>= 2.2.2), Rcpp (>=
                    0.12.15), rlang (>= 0.2.0), tibble (>= 1.3.1),
                    tidyselect (>= 0.2.3), utils
Suggests:           bit64 (>= 0.9.7), callr, covr (>= 3.0.1), DBI (>=
                    0.7.14), dbplyr (>= 1.2.0), dtplyr (>= 0.0.2),
                    ggplot2 (>= 2.2.1), hms (>= 0.4.1), knitr (>=
                    1.19), Lahman (>= 3.0-1), lubridate, MASS, mgcv (>=
                    1.8.23), microbenchmark (>= 1.4.4), nycflights13
                    (>= 0.2.2), rmarkdown (>= 1.8), RMySQL (>=
                    0.10.13), RPostgreSQL (>= 0.6.2), RSQLite (>= 2.0),
                    testthat (>= 2.0.0), withr (>= 2.1.1)
```

Comment: across is part of dplyr 1.1 from 1stjun2020, no need to go for GitHub development version it's available in cran, just use install.packages("dplyr"). Refer<https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/#:~:text=across()%20reduces%20the%20number,new%20verb%2C%20not%20four).>

Comment: Thanks, I still have the issue though. I updated the question above.

Comment: one reason might be the R version, R (≥ 3.2.0) is required for latest version of dplyr https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html

Comment: The R version is `$version.string [1] "R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)"`

Comment: Not sure then, but try post updating R to the latest version  >=4.0.0