# Summing values in a column and grouping by another column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a very basic question I am having trouble with. See the sample data below. I am trying create a new df with rolled up information under each persons name of their sum totals from each department.

I've been working with the dplyr package using the mutate and groupby and aggregate functions by to no luck. Is there a simple way to achieve this? The result of this task will then be plotted on a correlation plot.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Dept,      ~Mike,   ~Steve,   ~Tom,
  "Dept1",      1,      1,        0,
  "Dept1",      1,      1,        0,
  "Dept1",      0,      0,        1,
  "Dept2",      0,      1,        1,
  "Dept2",      0,      0,        0,
  "Dept2",      0,      1,        1,
  "Dept2",      0,      1,        0
)
```

Expected output:

```
result <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Dept,      ~Mike,   ~Steve,   ~Tom,
  "Dept1",      2,      2,        1,
  "Dept2",      1,      2,        2
)
```

Comment: In `base R` `aggregate(.~ Dept, df, sum)`

Comment: @akrun thank you for your time.  I receive an error.  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors. Dept is not numeric so I can't convert it to that.

Comment: Or in `dplyr` : `df %>% group_by(Dept) %>% summarize(across(everything(),sum))`

Comment: Based on your data, it is working fine for me

Comment: @akrun Very unusual. I can't explain that.

Comment: @Waldi that works great but I will say that the across function caused an error. I quickly read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615137/cant-find-function-across-in-mutate that this is not available in `dplyr` through cran. I ran `install.packages("devtools")`

Comment: @CiaranOBrien that’s out of date - `across` has been in the CRAN version for a while now.

Comment: @NickKennedy interesting, I had to run those two lines before it would work on my Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`summarise_all` is your friend here.

```
summarise_all(group_by(df, Dept), sum)
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#    Dept   Mike Steve   Tom
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Dept1     2     2     1
# 2 Dept2     0     3     2
```

Comment: Fantastic. Never knew about this function. great work and thank you.